# UNIX cc executable location

Tags: c, unix, executable, cc

When I compile a `.c` file using the `cc` command, it creates an `a.out` executable.  I've noticed that it creates the `a.out` file inside my current directory.  Is there a way to make the `a.out` file be created in the same directory as the `.c` file wherever I happen to be on the system?

for example if my current path is `~/desktop` and I type in the command:

```
cc path/to/my/file/example.c
```

It creates the `a.out` file in the `~/desktop` directory.  I would like it to create the `a.out` file in `path/to/my/file/a.out`

Comment: Besides the answers that have already been posted (and which should be helpful), I'd suggest learning how to write a `Makefile` (and perhaps how to use autoconf/automake if your project is likely to get bigger).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use the -o switch each time you call cc:

```
cc -o path/to/my/file/a.out path/to/my/file/example.c
```

or you can make a wrapper script like this:

mycc

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname=`dirname "$1"`
#enquoted both input and output filenames to make it work with files that include spaces in their names.
cmd="cc -o \"$dirname/a.out\" \"$1\""

eval $cmd
```

then you can invoke

```
./mycc path/to/my/file/example.c
```

and it will, in turn, call

```
cc -o "path/to/my/file/a.out" path/to/my/file/example.c
```

of course you can put mycc in $PATH so you can call it like:

```
mycc path/to/my/file/example.c
```

Comment: Is this possible as an alias?

Comment: You can also name output file like .c file i.e. `test.c` -> `test.out`, something like this: `cc $1 -o $(dirname $1)/$(basename $1 .c).out"`

Comment: @FUZxxl you can not simple alias cc to do this, cuz unfortunately you can't pass parameters to aliases (as I just found out :) ).

Comment: Okay (As I sad, I've no experiences in shell scripting).

Comment: this works great for what I need.  is there a way to also make it accept files whose path has a space in it?  ultimately, I would like to type mycc and drag the file into terminal and not worry if one of the folders in the file path has a space in it.

Comment: I edited the script above to enquote the input filename as well as the output filename. It shoould work now for filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the "-o" flag to define the output file. For example:

```
cc path/to/my/file/example.c -o path/to/my/file/a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `-o`.

```
cc path/to/my/file/example.c -o path/to/my/file/a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be not what you're looking for, but you can easily redirect the output of a compilation using the `-o` siwtch like this:

```
cc -o /a/dir/output b/dir/input.c
```

I don't know, how to archieve, what you want (auto replacement), but I guess you can do it with some bash like this: (I'm poor in scripting, untested and may be wrong):

```
i = "a/path/to/a/file.c" cc -o ${i%.c} $i
```

This should compile a file specified in i into an output file in same dir, but with the .c-suffix removed.

Comment: you need to provide path to a file not a directory. Your `-o` option has a missing filename.

Comment: As I sad, I'm bad at shell scripting. Shouldn't do this something like `$i = `a/b/file.c` -> `cc -o a/b/file a/b/file.c`?